# Create Com object

Tags: c#, com, wmplib

Hello I got the following exception.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {6BF52A4F-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

When i try to create o COM object with flow code( in c#)

```cs
Object instancePlayer = null;
Guid guid_IWMPPlayer = typeof(WMPLib.IWMPPlayer).GUID;
Guid guid_IUnknown = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid_IWMPPlayer);
instancePlayer = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: COM distinguishes between classes and interfaces.  And just like .NET, you cannot create an instance of an interface.  Your code doesn't make any sense, it is just a broken way to say `Type type = typeof(WMPLib.IWMPPlayer)`.  Nor does it make sense to try to use late binding and then still use the early bound interface types.  I can't see the intent of this code.  Use the ProgId for late binding.

Comment: I get exception at code : instancePlayer = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

Comment: sure you do. You want to create an instance of an interface, not implementation. How does your the framework know which implementation you want? How do you imagine a line like `var object = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(IDisposable));` should work?

Comment: By any chance are you running your code in 64-bit and trying to activate something that's 32-bit only?  I suspect Windows Media Player has a 64-bit version but it doesn't hurt to double check.  I was getting the same exception testing a COM component from 64-bit LinqPad until it dawned on me that it's an old 32-bit only COM component (one I had written in Delphi 7)

Answer (score 1):

COM uses `GUIDs` to identify classes and interfaces.  It looks like you're using an interface ID  (`IID`) called `IWMPPlayer` instead of a class ID (`CLSID`).  See if you can find a corresponding class for the player object and use the `GUID` of that.

Update: I looked up the class for you.  Get the `CLSID` like this...

```
Guid guid_WMPPlayer = typeof(WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer).GUID;
```

... and then pass this `CLSID` into `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID`.

Update 2: Can I just check though, that you definitely need to use these GUIDs?
Why not just do...

```
instancePlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
```

...?

Comment: Can you say more detail about it ??

Comment: but I want create a WMPLib.IWMPFolderMonitorServices object from WMPLib.IWMPPlayer Object

Comment: That sounds like a separate question; you didn't mention it before.  Does my answer resolve the question you posted?

Comment: I'm sorry. after this code I want Retrieve a pointer to IWMPFolderMonitorServices by calling QueryInterface through IWMPPlayer but I get excpetion here

Comment: No need to apologise.  Just post another question explaining what you tried, and showing the error you get.  Just like you did with this question :-)